# Choose an option from a select list with another select list with JavaScript/Angular/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When choosing an option from a select List, the other select list should take one by default.

Example:
The first Select is of types of documents (ID card, passport, etc.), so if I choose the ID card option, in the second select that is a list of countries, a country should be selected from that list. but I can not achieve that part in Typescript or javascript in the application. Please help

i'm using Angular 6 with Angular Material

HTML code:

```
<mat-form-field class="inputEde-form">
  <mat-label>Tipo Documento</mat-label>
  <mat-select name="documentType" id="documentTyps" 
              formControlName="DocumentTypeid"
              [ngClass]= "{'is-invalid': submitted && f.DocumentTypeid.errors}"
              (selectionChange)="setCountryByDocumentType($event)" required>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let DT of DTypes" [value]=DT.id>{{DT.documentType}}</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
                <mat-error *ngIf= "f.DocumentTypeid.errors?.required">Por favor seleccione este campo</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="inputEde-form">
              <mat-label> Pais de Residencia </mat-label>
              <mat-select formControlName="CountryCode" id="countriesList" required>
                <mat-option *ngFor = "let s of CountryCodes" [value] = s?.Code> {{s?.Country}}</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
              <mat-error *ngIf="f.CountryCode.errors?.required">Por favor seleccione este campo</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: It is not very clear. are you intending to change the CountryCodes depending on the documentType value or do you wish to automatically select a value in the second selection box depending on the first one ?

Comment: @RanikaNisal yes!, the first option (change the CountryCodes depending on the documentType value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First I believe you need to use (onSelectionChange) for the 2nd mat-select tag

   ```
   <mat-select name="documentType" id="documentTyps" 
         formControlName="DocumentTypeid"
         [ngClass]= "{'is-invalid': submitted && f.DocumentTypeid.errors}"
          required>
          <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="setCountryByDocumentType($event)" *ngFor="let DT of DTypes" [value]=DT.id>{{DT.documentType}}</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
   ```
2. Make countryCodes an observable ( You may have to do some imports )

   ```
   import { Observable, of } from rxjs;

   countryCodes : Observable<any[]>
   ```
3. In the setCountryByDocumentType method

   ```
   setCountryByDocumentType(event){
       if(event.isUserInput){
           console.log(event.source.value)
           if( event.source.value == something ){
               this.countryCodes = of(//The array you wish to pass);
           } 
       }
   }
   ```
4. Finally you should change the second mat-select

   ```
   <mat-select formControlName="CountryCode" id="countriesList" required>
           <mat-option *ngFor = "let s of CountryCodes | async" [value] = s?.Code> {{s?.Country}}</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
   ```